# Fitting a 480 pixel layout to a 320 pixel viewport

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, viewport

I'm using Dreamweaver's Fluid Grid layout system. While I've been able to create 3 designs (desktop/tablet/mobile), Dreamweaver uses the mobile viewport at 480 pixels wide. However, on iPhones, the viewport is actually 320 pixels wide, so a part of my design gets cut off on the right side.

Is there a metatag to shrink/scale the 480 pixel design down to fit to the 320 pixels, without affecting the tablet or desktop display?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution to your question:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, user-scalable=no" />
```

it sets the width of the content to 480px and lets the browser find the right scale.